# Linux: How can I download a git-repos without cloning it?

Tags: linux, git, proxy

I need a repository from Git for a project at work. Now our proxy blocks cloning from git, but on Windows, I still can download the repos as a `.zip` without git cloning it.

This project however runs on Linux and I need a repos for it, but of course `git clone <repos-Link>` doesn't work, due to our Proxy. Is there a way to just download the files so I can use them?

I'm looking for another way than downloading on Windows, and transferring the files manually

Comment: Note that a *repository* is a database containing *all* commits, typically many tens of thousands of them. Downloading a zip file gets you (the contents of) *one* commit: not the same thing at all.

Comment: Is this from github? You can download a ZIP from github under Linux without problems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the archive of a repo with [wget](https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/wget/)

`wget https://github.com/username/reponame/tarball/master`

Note that this is not the whole git repository, just the files.

You can then extract it with `tar -xvf master`